# Binding a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a report to display the records in Grid view based on some search parameters. In that one search filter is Drop down with Year values. The drop down should contain the years  starting from 2000 to current year. If the year changes it should automatically bind the next year.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I'm not understanding your question right, but it looks like you're just 'binding' a simple drop down to some year values.  If that's the case, i would put the following into your Page_Load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  for(int i = 2000, i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
  {
    MyDropDownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
  }
  //Select the current year initially
  MyDropDownList.SelectedIndex = MyDropDownList.Items.Count - 1;
}

//Later on in your Page_Load
MyGridView.DataSource = MyMethodOfFetchingData(MyDropDownList.SelectedValue);
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

At that point you need to use MyDropDownList.SelectedValue when retrieving your data to be displayed.

EDIT:
Added default selection of current year.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. How Can i access this value in C#? Because I have to send this one as Search parameter

Comment: That is OK friend. But you are not assigning any value to data item. Simply you are adding the text value. Then how can we use .SelectedValue Property?

Comment: MyDropDownlist.Items.FindByValue(Today.Year.ToString()).Selected=True;

I mentioned it below.

Comment: Additionally, if the user is specifying the Search criteria, he'll pick the date and set the SelectedValue that way.  Checking to see if SelectedValue is set would be a good step before fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `Date.Today`, you need to give us some more information but there are plenty of variables in VB.NET / C# that reference the current year.

```
Me.MyDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(CType(Today.Year, String)).Selected=True
```

[edit portion]

The above is to bind the value to the current year.  Just a note, it may be worthwhile to store the years in a database starting from 2000 till say some max number and then to retrieve the rows:

```
SELECT TheYear FROM YourTable WHERE TheYear <= YEAR(GetDate())
```

That will return 2000 till the current year.  This will make your code reusable as you can then just bind the rows to some data set or data control.  It also avoids having weird for loops in your page load event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but I think this is close:

There are essentially 3 components:

```
asp:DropDownList id="ddl1"
asp:SqlDataSource
asp:GridViewControl
```

Configure the data source to use `ddl1.SelectedValue` in the `WHERE` clause. (Parameter Source: Control, Value = `ddl1.SelectedValue`)

Bind the Grid View to the DataSource

At this point, the simplest way to get what you want is to enable `AutoPostBack` on `ddl1`, and let the magic happen itself.

Comment: Is there any class to implement this?

Comment: The Autopostback will cause a page refresh, and the databinding should automagically take control.  You don't need to write any code, just configure the properties in the designer.